# 検証ツールで選択した場所のコードの位置をsassで確認する方法

Tags: html, css, wordpress

ワードプレスでホームページの作成をしています。
初心者です。

マルチポストです。

[リンク](https://teratail.com/questions/r023qisgg7bu2v)

検証ツールで選択した部分が、style.css：２と記入されます。
これは、ワードプレスのプラグインの、
WP-SCSSを使用しています、そして、これでsassをcssに直すと、
２行目に一列にずっとコードが並んでいるようになるからなのですが。

これをstyle.css：２ではなく、sassのファイルで、位置が表示されるようにしたいと
考えています、

ネットにある方法を試しても、書いてあるボタンがないなどの理由で、
途中から上手く行かなくなります。

https://blog.cgfm.jp/garyu/archives/2806
「 Chromeのデベロッパー ツールのテストを有効にする」 が表示されない
(英語で翻訳機能を使いながらやり、１つ有効にしてみました)

https://blog.webico.work/chrome-live-sass

これは開発者ツールのSettings > General > Sourcesにある、「Enable CSS source maps」にチェックがあると表示されるようですがチェックしてもされません。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1):

WP-SCSS の設定で、Source Map Mode をlnlineにしたら出来ました。
一緒に、ご思案頂きありがとうございました。